# Vim: Space bar in insert mode creates integers

Tags: vim, amazon-ec2, mingw, vi

I'm using MINGW on a Windows 7 machine to ssh to an EC2 instance (Ubuntu) on which I would like to use vim as my text editor. If I run `vim test.txt`, enter Insert mode, and type `this is a test`, however, vim interprets each of the spaces in that sequence as an integer:

[image]

Does anyone know what could possible cause this? I tried updating vim with `sudo apt-get install vim` and was told I already had the most up to date vim. Any suggestions others can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up purging and then reinstalling vim:

> Purge to remove the package config files: `sudo apt-get purge vim`
>
> Clean out any personalizations: `rm -Rf ~/.vim ~/.vimrc ~/.viminfo`
>
> Reinstall Vim again: `sudo apt-get install vim`

That solved the problem, but I'm still interested to know what could possibly have created the issue. (Why would the space bar create increasing integer runs on a fresh EC2 instance? Is this some strange key mapping issue?)